# How can i assign half command to variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash

This command works fine

```
find . -name "test"
```

But i want to do like this in shell script

```
$FIND = "find . -name "
```

so that i can use  `$FIND "test"`

but its not working

Comment: How not working? Perhaps delete the whitespace around the `=` operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the statement:

```
$Find = "find . -name "
```

There are two things wrong with this:

1. The shell requires that there be no spaces around the `=` in an assignment.
2. `$Find` is the value of a variable.  It is not the variable itself.

Thus, to assign a value to `Find`, use:

```
Find="find . -name "
```

It is not possible to run:

```
$Find test
```

This approach is portable but limited.  In the long run, it is better to use arrays for this sort of problem.

Lastly, it is best practices not to use all caps for variable names.  The system uses all caps for its variables and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one.

#### Using arrays

One can define an array for this as follows:

```
Find=(find . -name)
```

The array can be used as follows:

```
"${Find[@]}" test
```

For the simple example that you showed, there is no difference between the array solution and the simpler variable solution.    Once the command gets a bit more complicated and requires, say, quotes or escapes, though, an array must be used.

Comment: how can i use arrays for this scenario

Comment: I updated the answer with an array example.  For greater detail, the [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), as cited by Gordon, is an excellent resource.

Comment: A function would be better for this than an array.

Answer (score 3):

See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Short summary: depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, use either a function or an array.

For your specific example, I'd use a function:

```
find_name() {
    find . -name "$1"
}

find_name "test"
```

Comment: Or an alias, given the argument's at the end.

Comment: @paxdiablo That'd work too. I tend to prefer functions over aliases because they work in scripts as well as interactively, and they give more control over arguments -- in this case, I don't think either of those is relevant, so an alias should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

What about use `eval`? That seems to be the easiest way if you need to use a variable. It could look like this:

```
find="find . -name"
eval $find test
```

But you should [be careful with `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead).

Anyway **alias** or **function** would be better for this, if you don't have any special requirements for a variable. Alias is absolutely the easiest way, function is more flexible (you can put there any logic you need):

```
# alias
alias find="find . -name"
find test

# function
find() {
    find . -name "$*"
}
find test
```

Comment: OK, great, use an **alias** then. It's designed exactly for what you need. Use of a variable for this purpose is very weird, therefore there is no straightforward way to execute a content in a variable.